# Make sure associated object belongs to a User when creating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

A User can have many dogs, and I have this in my Dogs controller:

```
def new
  @dog = Dog.new
end

def create
  # How do I create the Dog, so that it belongs to current_user?
end
```

Then in my new.html.erb I have the following form:

```
<h1> Create a new dog </h1>
<%= form_for @dog  do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create!' %>
<% end %>
```

I am wondering how to create the dog so that it belongs to the current_user who submitted the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a `current_user` available in your controller, and a `has_many :dogs` association in the User model, you can:

```
current_user.dogs.create(params[:dog])
```